# Data class .copy only if nullable parameter is not null

Tags: kotlin

I have a Front-End application that sends me Data to update my User (updatedUser). Since I don't want to send the whole Userdata, I'm only sending the data that has changed. Now I want to Update my Userdata with the changes provided, so I'd like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this than just a list of ifs/lets. I'm quite new to kotlin, so don't expect too much from me^^

Not so elegant way:

```
changeData.firstname?.let { updatedUser.firstname = it }
changeData.lastname?.let { updatedUser.lastname = it }
...
```

Expected (doesn't work - type mismatch):

```
updatedUser.copy( 
    firstname = changeData?.firstname,  
    lastname = changeData?.lastname, 
    ...)
```

Comment: Not an answer: how can the user reset a value to null with this design? What do you actually gain by not sending the complete user information?

Comment: Well the userdata contains information that should not be changeable (e.g. the unique userId generated by keycloak) and we have some properties that are only changable through a separate API-Call (e.g. the language), so I don't want to send the whole object. I'm also saving bandwidth that way.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to send data that may not be changed. I'm suggesting sending all the data that can be changed (i.e. all the inputs of your form), and save that data.

Comment: Well that would then mean more code in the frontend, because then i have to convert one object to another... Or is TypeScript able to handle that with `as`?

Answer (score 0):

the reason you get a type mismatch is There is a string type and a string nullable type

`var variableName:String = "myData" // if you want a non nullable
var variableName:String? = "myDataThatCouldBeNull" // if you want a string that could be null`

Comment: Well that's also what the compíler is telling me ;)
I know why it fails, i just don't know how to solve it somewhat elegent^^